# Python routes non-parameter wildcards

Tags: python, routes, pylons

I am using pylons and have a trouble with the terminating '/' character, simply, I want to ignore it.
My route file looks like this:

```
    with map.submapper(path_prefix='/app', controller='app') as m:
            m.connect('{_:/?}', action='index')
```

and I would like much to write `/?` instead of `{_:/?}`, as it sets the request `_` field to something, and I have to unset it manually if I redirect. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "`{_:/?}`" or "`/?`", use "":

```
with map.submapper(path_prefix='/app', controller='app') as m:
    m.connect('', action='index')
```